# $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/ p \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ infinite

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ the
ring of integers of complex $p$-adic numbers
$\mathbb{C}_p$ which are defined as completion of alg closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ with respect $\vert \cdot \vert_p$ (extended from $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$. It is known that
$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ is *not
a Noetherian ring*
(e.g. A. M. Robert, A Course in p-adic Analysis,
page 135).

How this fact can be explicitely used to show that
$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/
p \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ is infinite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is not a good idea to show $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}/p \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}$ is infinite from the fact that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}$ is not noetherian and then some makeshift ring theoretic proposition or argument. Rather, I would claim that any good proof which shows that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}$ is not noetherian already shows immediately -- namely, by exhibiting the ideal structure of the ring -- that the quotient $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}/p \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}$ is not noetherian as well.

We have to use something more about the specific rings and ideals in question anyway, because obviously there are non-noetherian rings $A$ with ideals $I$ such that $A/I$ is finite; in fact, there are [non-noetherian local domains $R$ of characteristic $0$, with $p$ contained in their maximal ideal and $R/p$ finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4228717/96384), so we would need to prove a severely fine-tuned extra proposition here, on top of proving non-noetherianness of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}$; that seems like total overkill.

Because I also believe that whatever proves that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}$ is not noetherian already proves *much more* than that, and in particular infinitude of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}/p\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}$. This "whatever", from which everything follows, is what one should actually understand about the ring in question, and I believe it is nothing else than the unique extension of the $p$-adic absolute value $\lvert \cdot \rvert_p$ (normed to, say, $\lvert p \rvert_p = p^{-1}$) from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q_p$ to an algebraic closure $\overline{ \mathbb Q_p}$ to its completion $\mathbb C_p$.

Crucially, on $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$ as well as on $\mathbb C_p$, its value group consists of ($0$ and) *all rational powers of $p$*. This, and the fact that it is an absolute (nonarchimedean) value, tell us **everything** about the ideal structure of the ring by translating it into some undergrad exercise in open or closed intervals. Indeed, it follows now that the ring

$$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p} = \{x \in \mathbb C_p: \lvert x \rvert_p \le 1 \}$$

has unit group

$$\mathcal{O}^\times_{\mathbb C_p} = \{x \in \mathbb C_p: \lvert x \rvert_p = 1 \}.$$

With that, it further follows that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}$ has two kinds of non-zero ideals: On the one hand,

$$I^c_q := \{x \in \mathbb C_p: \lvert x \rvert_p \color{red}{\le} p^{-q} \}$$

for non-negative *rationals* $q$; these are the *principal* ideals, and any $x \in \mathbb C_p$ with  $\lvert x \rvert_p = p^{-q}$ is a generator. On the other hand

$$I^o_r := \{x \in \mathbb C_p: \lvert x \rvert_p \color{red}{<} p^{-r} \}$$

for any non-negative real number $r$; these ideals are not finitely generated; a set of generators is given by the underlying set of any sequence $x_n$ in $\mathbb C_p$ such that the sequence of the values $\lvert x_n\rvert_p$ is increasing and has limit $p^{-r}$.

The sheer existence of non-finitely generated ideals shows that ${O}_{\mathbb C_p}$ is not noetherian; of course any monotonic decreasing non-stabilising sequence of real or rational numbers now also translates to non-stabilising increasing ideal chains.

Actually, we also get $I^c_{q_1} \cdot I^c_{q_2} = I^c_{q_1+q_2}$ and $I^o_{r_1} \cdot  I^o_{r_2} = I^o_{r_1+r_2}$ and $I^c_q \cdot I^o_r = I^o_{q+r}$ almost for free, as well as e.g.

$$\bigcup_{q_n} I^c_{q_n} = \begin{cases} I^c_m \text{ if } m = \min\{q_n\}\text{ exists} \\ I^o_{\inf(q_n)} \text{ otherwise } \end{cases} \qquad \text{ etc. etc.}$$

In particular, this implies that ${O}_{\mathbb C_p}$ is a local ring with maximal ideal

$$\mathfrak{m}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}} = \{x \in \mathbb C_p: \lvert x \rvert_p < 1 \} = I^o_0$$

(and immediately the maximal ideal is idempotent, $\mathfrak{m}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}} = \mathfrak{m}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}}^n$ for all $n$), while of course $p \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p} = I^c_1$, and it is obvious, not only that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}/p \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}$ is infinite, but that its ideals are in one-to-one correspondence  to the $I^c_q$ and $I^o_r$ where $q$ and $r$ are any rational or real numbers between $0$ and $1$, in particular there are tons of infinitely ascending ideal chains in there, in particular that quotient is as far from being noetherian as the whole ring, in particular it is very infinite.

Check out related questions [Ring of integers of $\mathbb{C}_p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3055090/96384) and [Why is $O_{\mathbb{C}_p}/p$ not perfect?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2093096/96384).

Comment: Thank's for the detailed answer. I will need
some time to check all details. 

One point I not understand. When 
you introduce the unit group


$$\mathcal{O}^\times_{\mathbb C_p} = 
\{x \in \mathbb C_p: \lvert x \rvert_p = 1 \}$$

you claim that it has two kinds of
non-zero ideals and one such ideal
is 

$$ I^c_q := \{x \in \mathbb C_p: \lvert x \rvert_p \color{red}{\le} p^{-q} \}$$

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't it contradict to the definition of
$\mathcal{O}^\times_{\mathbb C_p}$?

Also you wrote that ${O}^\times_{\mathbb C_p}$
is local ring with maximal ideal

$$   \mathfrak{m}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}} = \{x \in \mathbb C_p: \lvert x \rvert_p < 1 \} = I^o_0   $$

Are you sure that you really mean 
${O}^\times_{\mathbb C_p}$ and *not*
${O}_{\mathbb C_p}$ here? More generally, I doubt
that the unit group ${O}^\times_{\mathbb C_p}$
has a well-defined ring structure

Comment: Of course it's the ring $O_{\mathbb C_p}$ which I am talking about and which has ideals etc. I'll try to change the wording to make that clearer.

Comment: dear Torsten, +1, but I think you have a typo where you write "I think there are, for any prime $p$, non-noetherian rings contained in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $A/pA=\mathbb{F}_p$". indeed, every subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at some set of primes, and is hence Noetherian

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom: You are right. I think what I had in mind when I wrote that was $\bar \mathbb Q$, an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$, and certain rings of the form in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2390771/96384. I have edited that section together with a link to an even stronger example now.

Answer (score 3):

Torsten’s answer is excellent, and depends on the observation that there is infinite ramification. But there is also infinite residue-field extension degree. In particular, the field $\mathcal K=\mathcal O_{\Bbb C_p}/\mathcal M$ (where $\mathcal M$ is the maximal ideal of the integer ring here) contains representatives of every element of $\overline{\Bbb F_p}$, the algebraic closure of the prime field $\Bbb F_p$. Thus $\mathcal K$ is infinite, and this is is all the more so for $\mathcal O_{\Bbb C_p}/p\mathcal O_{\Bbb C_p}$.

Perhaps I should point out that noetherianness has little to do with the case: if $\mathcal U$ is the maximal unramified extension of $\Bbb Q_p$, with ring of integers $\mathcal O_{\mathcal U}$, this last is still a discrete valuation ring, with prime element $p$, and thus noetherian. But $\mathcal O_{\mathcal U}/p\mathcal O_{\mathcal U}$ is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Note that an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is contained in $\mathbb{C}_p$. In particular each $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}_p$. But then it is clear that if $\bar{f} \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ then any lift $f$ to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}_p$ - in particular $\bar{f}$ has a root in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/p \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$.

But this implies that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/p \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ contains an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$, which is infinite.

Comment: yes, this argument works. can it also be derived directly from the non-Noetherness of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$? That's my main point of interest.

Comment: You actually can't derive this directly from the non-Noetherianness of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ alone. There are non-Noetherian totally ramified field extensions $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ for which $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}$ is finite. An example can be found by taking the field $K = \mathbb{Q}_p(p^{-\infty})$ (which is totally ramified).

Comment: But @Geoff, $p \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p} \subsetneq \mathfrak{m}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}}$, and I assume the ideal generated by $p$ in the examples you allude to (as opposed to the maximal ideals) would also have an infinite quotient. (I also think that arguing with non-Noetherianness seems a bit strange here, but I don't think your argument refutes the possibilty of proving it that way.)

Comment: On the other hand, @user7391733, of course you will need at least a little more knowledge about the ring $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}$ (with its ideal $(p)$) than that it's not Noetherian -- because I'm sure you will come up with examples of non-Noetherian rings which have quotients that are finite.

Comment: what I had in mind is based exactly on observation by Torsten that $p \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p} \subsetneq \mathfrak{m}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}}$ and the goal is to show that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have moreover $p \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p} \subsetneq \mathfrak{m}^n_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C_p}}$. This might be look promising because $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ is infinite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and for *finite extensions* of $L \supset \mathbb{Q}_p$ we have formula $n_L= f_Le_L$ where $pO_L = \pi_L^eO_L$ but  I don't see how I can finish this idea